# Is it possible to configure payment methods on category-specific or product-specific basis in Satchmo?

Tags: django, satchmo

I have a Satchmo-powered shop that needs to have a special item category available only for users that pay by cash-on-delivery method.

Short of hard-coding the checkout process, is there any easy way I can use to restrict payment options for particular product category to cash-on-delivery only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is that Satchmo emits signals almost for every action, so on construction of payment methods form you have to listen to a specific signal and then redefine *methods* kwarg variable which gets passed to listener:

```
from payment.signals import payment_methods_query

def on_payment_methods_query(sender, methods=None, cart=None, order=None, contact=None, **kwargs):
    if not cart.is_empty:
        for item in cart.cartitem_set.all():
            special_products = settings.SPECIAL_PRODUCTS #(1, 15, 25, 75)
            if item.product_id in special_products:
                # methods is a list of (option_value, option_label) tuples
                methods = [m for m in methods if m[0] in ('COD',)]
                return
payment_methods_query.connect(on_payment_methods_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem in the previous answer (I know because I just tried myself), in the following line:

```
methods = [m for m in methods if m[0] in ('COD',)] # won't have the desired effect
```

Problem is, out of the original methods list, a completely new list is created, and stored in the same variable name. This will not affect the original list that Satchmo passed in, so Satchmo won't even know. 
What you need to do is actually modify the list object passed in, using methods like 'methods.remove(...)'.

In the particular example, it should be something like this:

```
disallowed_methods = [m for m in methods if m[0] not in ('COD',)]
for m in disallowed_methods:
    methods.remove(m)
```

Maybe my code is not the most elegant; maybe someone can improve it, and possibly integrate it with the original answer.